# How to detect if modal element is open in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have the modal bellow with `class="modal fade"`,

when user click to open the modal the method `showCreateGroup()` is called.

```
<div class="modal fade"
     id="groupModal"
     tabindex="-1"
     role="dialog"
     aria-labelledby="groupModalLabel"
     aria-hidden="true">
     <div v-bind:class="{'modal-lg':modalLarge, 'modal-dialog':true}" role="document">
     ...
```

I'm wondering how is it possible to listen to that element in `watch` method and detects if it's shown?

Note : when the modal is open the class attribute converts from `modal fade` to `modal fade show`

Comment: I'm not familar with vue.js. Within the compoent, can you execute plain javascript that looks for all three css classes at your target object?